# Colored tabulated data

Tags: tables

I was attempting to get this color effects in my tabulated data:

[image]

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\rowcolors{2}{blue!80!green!80!yellow!50}{green!70!yellow!40}
%\rowcolors[\hline]{3}{.!50!White}{}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
%\hline
%\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Country List} \\
\hline
Country Name& ISO ALPHA 2 \\
\hline
Aland Islands & AX   \\
Albania &AL  \\
Algeria    &DZ  \\
American Samoa & AS \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do the white lines between the rows and columns need to show up in the new table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I defined some new colors to make it more similar to your example image. I also reduced the thickness of the rules and their numbers, and turned them white.

I also defined a new column type `C` that centers the content, but also has a minimum width of `3cm`.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5mm}

\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{96,162,216}
\definecolor{mblue}{RGB}{208,221,240}
\definecolor{lblue}{RGB}{233,239,247}

\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\rowcolors{2}{lblue}{mblue}
\begin{tabular}{C|C} \rowcolor{dblue}
Country Name & ISO ALPHA 2 \\ \hline 
Aland Islands & AX   \\
Albania &AL  \\
Algeria    &DZ  \\
American Samoa & AS \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```